# Set permissions with icacls with rules from a textfile in powershell

Tags: powershell, permissions, sql-grant, icacls

I'm trying to use Icacls in Powershell, to set local permissions. I have a textfile from which I get the permissions. I do it like this, because I want to change permissions of a lot of folders and I don't want to change the script every time.

Textfile looks like this (german names used):

```
/grant:r SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F) /grant:r Administratoren:(OI)(CI)(F) /grant:r mydomain\Domänen-Admins:(OI)(CI)(F) /inheritance:r
/grant:r mydomain\user1:(OI)(CI)(R) /grant:r myodomain\user2:(OI)(CI)(C)   
/grant:r mydomain\user2:(OI)(CI)(F) /deny mydomain\user2:(DE)
```

My code looks like this:

```
$AccessLine=cat .\Lines.txt
$ica=$AccessLine[0..2]
icacls.exe $path "ica"     #$path is the path of folder which should be modified
```

It always says invalid parameter given. I cannot write the /grant:r part in line with icacls $path because I also need to set /deny permissions. I would like to set all the permissions with just one command. Is this possible?

Comment: Okay I think I know where the problems are: first thing is, that I needed to write the permissions with double quotes `"grant:r" "SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F)"` etc. in the textfile. The second thing is, that the script only works if I set `$ica=$AccessLine[0]`. So there must be something wrong with reading out the lines of the file and giving it to icacls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 sets of commands that need to be run. The `$ica=$AccessLine[0]` line works because you are only calling one of the lines. You are asking for a loop so that each line can be processed.

```
$AccessLines = cat .\Lines.txt
$AccessLines | ForEach-Object{& icacls.exe $path $_}
```

FWIW `cat` is an alias for `Get-Content` which returns files as arrays of lines.